# How to refresh a ListView in the activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListActivity class. It has a button which sorts the item according to one of their attributes. But it so happens that the item are getting sort by their name but upon clicking the item of its original position is getting executed. 
Here is the code snippet :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

        mButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.mButton);

        ArrayList<myObject> ListData = new ArrayList<myObject>();

        back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.likethis);
        label.setText("List");
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        //Manager -- class that reads from the sdcard
        Manager plm = new Manager();

        // get all files from sdcard
        //getList() function of Manager class
        //List declared outside oncreate()
        this.List = plm.getList(); 

        final ArrayList<myObject> backUp = new ArrayList<myObject>(songsList);

        if(sortCalled) {
            mButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m_checked));
            mButton.setChecked(true);
            Collections.sort(List);

            notifyDataChanged(List);
        }
        else {
            mButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m_unchecked));
            mButton.setChecked(false);
            notifyDataChanged(backUp);
        }

        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }

        });

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override 
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //ArrayList <Song> temp;
                ((SimpleAdapter) PlayListActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(s, new Filter.FilterListener() {

                    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

        });

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(mButton.isChecked()){
                    mButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m_checked));
                    Collections.sort(List);
                    sortCalled = true;
                    notifyDataChanged(List);
                }
                else{
                    sortCalled = false;
                    mButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m_unchecked));
                    notifyDataChanged(backUp);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    public void settingListAdapter(SimpleAdapter adapter){
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index
                int Index = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                // Sending Index to MainActivity
                in.putExtra("Index", Index);
                setResult(100, in);
                // Closing ListView
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void notifyDataChanged(ArrayList<Song> songsList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setListAdapter(null);
        sortCalled = true;
        ArrayList<myObject> songsListData = new ArrayList<myObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            myObject ob = sList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            ListData.add(ob);
        }

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
       // int j = 0;
        for(myObject i : ListData){
            HashMap<String, String> feed = new HashMap<String, String>();
            feed.put("Title", i.getTitle());
            array.add(feed);

        }
        BaseAdapter adapter1;
       // int i = 0;
        // Adding menuItems to ListView
         adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(this, array,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"Title" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Title });

        setListAdapter(adapter1);
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index
                int Index = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                // Sending songIndex to MainActivity
                in.putExtra("Index", Index);
                setResult(100, in);
                // Closing ListView
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: how you would like to refresh the listview by clicking any button or automatically by setting time?

Comment: By click any button thats what I want to do ... cant I integrate sorting and refreshing into one button??

Comment: Then call the function on the onclick of the button from which you are getting data and that data to list adapter.

Comment: can you provide the code... because it isn't happening that way...:/

Comment: I am kinda doing the same thing look at the code...:O

Comment: Refer the following [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this.when you sort the data of your listview.it is working me perfectly

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: You mean within the sort function??

Comment: after sort data.also a way of using asynctask class to do this task

Comment: I have used it in notifyDataChanged() function. :O isnt it the proper place to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you make a change to adapter you should call notifyDataSetChanged() in UIThread

Please check [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m38s) to understand listView better

**Edit**
For an ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the `add, insert, remove, and clear` functions on the Adapter.

When an ArrayAdapter is constructed, it holds the reference for the List that was passed in. If you were to pass in a List that was a member of an Activity, and change that Activity member later, the ArrayAdapter is still holding a reference to the original List. The Adapter does not know you changed the List in the Activity.

Your choices are:

Use the functions of the ArrayAdapter to modify the underlying List `(add, insert, remove, clear, etc.)`
Re-create the ArrayAdapter with the new List data. (Uses a lot of resources and garbage collection.)
Create your own class derived from BaseAdapter and ListAdapter that allows changing of the underlying List data structure.
Use the notifyDataSetChanged every time the list is update. To call it on the UI-Thread use the runOnUiThread method of the Activity. Then notifyDataSetChanged will work.

Comment: what is notifyDatachanged() ? why are you using it ?

Comment: As i told you I was trying to sort them so I had a backup arraylist and one sorted list and I just sent either of them in the notifyDataChanged() function which sets it up in the adapter. I thought assigning a new adapter everytime the function is called could curb this problem but it was not so.

Comment: ok can you remove notifydatachanged() and replace it with lv.notifyDataSetChanged() and let me know what error is there?

Comment: and yes please sort the array and also make changes in adapter before calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: instead of setListAdapter(null); use invalidate() and invalidateViews()

Comment: shouldnt it be deferNotifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: it is notifyDataSetChanged()  go through the video in my answer  to know about it

Comment: okay I will do ... :) thanx a lot... :) I will let post any update...:)

Comment: I am using BaseAdapter not ArrayAdapter... does the same goes with BaseAdapter??

Comment: Base adapter is parent class for others so it doesn't matter try whether it works

Comment: So what all do I need to create and override in the custom adapter class??

Comment: Plus if you see the notifydatachanged() function I am doing exactly dat.... creating a new adapter and feeding it with list data and trying the setListAdapter() function... but it is not helping

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18813/discussion-between-saurabh-and-deepak-samuel-rajan)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() function. It might work.

If you are using a SimpleCursorAdapter, calling requery() on the cursor attached to the adapter will automatically refresh the adapter and attached view.

If it's BaseAdapter content changes, you call BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() which will tell the ListView to update itself.

In other words you only need to make the following tiny change:

```
public void setValue(Object newValue) {
     this.value = newValue;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Actually, since you're changing the state of an existing item (rather than adding new ones etc) then notifyDataSetInvalidated() would be a better choice.